# Set a different module port for appengine-maven-plugin

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I'm developing a Java GAE app. When I run the devserver, the default instance is running on 8080 port and others are running on random ports. Is there a way to change the default port for each module using config or any?

Ref:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/routing#Java_Routing_in_the_development_server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GAE modules on development server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113299/gae-modules-on-development-server)